# Table joins with between clause performances

Tags: performance, oracle11g

I want to fetch a column from one table using between condition as in the below query. I joined the tables but it takes lot of time if the tables are having 100k records. Is there any way to rewrite this ?

I need a.grade in the result of my value lies between a.low and a.high.. there can be many matches for one value.

Select a.grade, b.val
From tbl1 a, tbl2b
Where b.val between a.low and a.high;

Also I have an index on (low,high) but optimiser is not using it

Comment: What indexes do you have?  Do you really have 100,000 rows in both tables and no other predicate?  I would expect at a minimum for there to be some additional join predicate between the tables.  Otherwise, you're trying to compare each of 100,000 records in b against each of 100,000 ranges in a which would be 100,000 * 100,000 = 10,000,000,000 or 10 billion comparisons.  If that's what you want to do, I'd wager you have a fundamental issue with your data model

Comment: I have indexes on low and high column in table A but plan show its not being used.  To be specific, I have around 180000 records in tblA and 120000 records in tblB. There are no predictes to join and thats how the data model is now. Trying to check any other way to optimize.

Comment: Can you explain what `tblA` and `tblB` represent?  If you have 180,000 intervals, I assume that you have lots of overlapping intervals.  So if you have 120,000 rows in `tblB`, are you going to be getting hundreds or thousands of matches per row?  So your query will end up with hundreds of millions of results?  I struggle to come up with a situation where that would make logical sense.

Comment: Yes there are overlapping intervals which makes the processes costly. One tbl has list of IPAddresses and other has subnet info and there is an existing logic that is built across these tbles to see which subnet each IP belongs to. These come from a network db and the data model is set up this way and so just trying to work with what is present.  We are working to change the model itself which will take some weeks, but meanwhile this query was running for 30-40 mins before and suddenly it runs for 5-6 hours and times out. The volume of data is same. Thats why the analysis